# Uniform Variables Display a black screen using jogl

Tags: opengl, glsl, jogl

I've been piecing together a basic game engine using jogl and have hit a pretty big road bump when it comes to accessing and/or updating uniform variables in my shader code.

Here is how I am allocating the Matrix and associated Buffer:

```
protected float[] test_matrix = {
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
};
protected int matrix_size = test_matrix.length;

FloatBuffer matrix_buffer = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(test_matrix, 0, matrix_size);
```

Here is the code in question:

```
shaderProgram = gl.glCreateProgram();
gl.glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertShader);
gl.glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragShader);

pmvmatrix = new PMVMatrix();
transmatrix_location = gl.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "transformationMatrix");
gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(transmatrix_location, 400, false, matrix_buffer);

pmvmatrix.glMatrixMode(GLMatrixFunc.GL_MODELVIEW);
pmvmatrix.glLoadIdentity();

gl.glBindAttribLocation(shaderProgram, 0, "position");
gl.glBindAttribLocation(shaderProgram, 1, "color");

gl.glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
```

And here is my vertex shader:

```
#version 400 core

in vec3 position;

out vec3 color;

uniform mat4 transformationMatrix;

void main(void){
    gl_Position = transformationMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
    color = vec3(position.x+0.5,1.0,position.y+0.5);
}
```

The shaders are compiling successfully and if I remove the "transformationMatrix *" in my vertex shader, the object renders properly.

Is my matrix just being passed as a 1X16 matrix rather than a 4X4? Am I using the glUniformMatrix4fv function properly?

Comment: Is `transmatrix_location` less than zero?

Answer (score 2):

```
transmatrix_location = gl.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "transformationMatrix");
...
gl.glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
```

Wrong way around.  [Link, *then* Get](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glGetUniformLocation.xhtml):

> ... The actual locations assigned to uniform variables are not known
>   until the program object is linked successfully. After linking has
>   occurred, the command `glGetUniformLocation` can be used to obtain the
>   location of a uniform variable. ...

Comment: Switched those around, still getting a blank screen. My transmatrix_location variable is returning '0'. Should that be a non-zero number?

Comment: @PeterHope: Nope, zero is perfectly valid.

Comment: Hmm, well now I'm calling glLinkProgram, glGetUniformLocation, glUniformMatrix4fv, and then setting the matrix mode and loading identity. Is that correct?

Comment: @Peter.Hope: No, that's not correct either. You must make the GLSL program active (by calling `glUseProgram (...)` before you can meaningfully call `glUniformMatrix4fv (...)`. The other portions of the shader API let you pass around a program by name, but that's not one of them... it uses whatever program is currently active (which is **0** judging by your code).

Comment: For bonus points, there exists a part of the shader API that will let you pass a program name for uniforms. If your implementation supports it (core in GL 4.1), you will find `glProgramUniform* (...)` allows you to specify uniform data without changing the bound program object.